# Using the code behind file to authenticate

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms, code-behind

I have a `Asp.Net web Forms` application , in which i added this authentification form ( [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server">
private bool SiteSpecificAuthenticationMethod(string UserName, string Password)
{
    // Insert code that implements a site-specific custom 
    // authentication method here.
    //
    // This example implementation always returns false.
    return false;
}

private void OnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    bool Authenticated = false;
    Authenticated = SiteSpecificAuthenticationMethod(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);

    e.Authenticated = Authenticated;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server"
                OnAuthenticate="OnAuthenticate">
            </asp:Login>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to put the script of authentification in the code behind class.

1. How can i edit my snippet to do this ?
2. Is it the best way to add a customized authentification form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i edit my snippet to do this ?

To the corresponded code-behind file: `Default.aspx.cs`, move this code:

```
private bool SiteSpecificAuthenticationMethod(string UserName, string Password)
{
    // Insert code that implements a site-specific custom 
    // authentication method here.
    //
    // This example implementation always returns false.
    return false;
}

protected void OnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    bool Authenticated = false;
    Authenticated = SiteSpecificAuthenticationMethod(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);

    e.Authenticated = Authenticated;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Change the `OnAuthenticate` access-modifier to `protected`:

```
    protected void OnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        bool Authenticated = false;
        Authenticated = SiteSpecificAuthenticationMethod(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);

        e.Authenticated = Authenticated;
    }
```

> Is it the best way to add a customized authentification form?

Yes, if you want to customize the authentication process, I don't see any other option.

Comment: I did this but i got an error `CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'OnAuthenticate' and no extension method 'OnAuthenticate' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' was found (a using directive or a reference to assembly is it missing?)`